# How to use mongodb node.js and angular js to create a course registration portal

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a course registration portal. Everything was working correctly, but when the student tries to click to register their courses the button doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
FIRST I CREATE A STUDENT SCHEMA
var studentSchema = new Schema({
    firstname:{type: String, required: true},
    middlename:{type: String, required: true},
    lastname:{type: String, required: true},
    department:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'department', required: true },
    Courses:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'course'}],
  });
```

The student schema has  a sub-document Courses which is an array of courseSchema

```
var courseSchema = new Schema({
   title: {type: String, required: true},
   code:{type: String, required: true, unique: true},
   unit:{type: String, required: true},
   level:{type: String, required: true},
   department:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'department'}
});
```

I also create an API to get all the courses in mongodb where student.department is equal to course.department here is the code

```
router.get('/student/getcourses/:studentid', function(req, res){
if (!req.params.studentid) {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
        "message": "Not found, studentid is required"
    });
        return;
}
Student
.findOne({_id : req.params.studentid})
.exec(function(err, student){
    if (err) {
        sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
    }else{
        Course
        .find({department : student.department})
        .populate('department')
        .exec(function(err, courses){
            if (err) {
                sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
            }else{
                sendJSONresponse(res, 200, courses);
            }
        });
    }
 });
});
```

I also create an API that will register a particular course for a student here is the code

```
router.post('/student/courseReg/:studentid', function(req, res){
if (!req.params.studentid) {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
        "message": "Not found, studentid is required"
    });
        return;
}
Student
.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.studentid, {$push: {regCourses:req.body.course}})
.exec(function(err, student){
    if (err) {
        sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
    }else{
        sendJSONresponse(res, 200, " registration successfull");
    }
 });
});
```

on the front-end with angularjs here is what i did

```
$http.get('/api/student/getcourses/' + $scope.studentid)
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.courses = data ; 
    $scope.register = function(course){
            $http.post('/api/student/courseReg/' + $scope.studentid, course)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
    };
})
.error(function (e) {
    return e;
});
```

and here is the html code

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table"> 
         <thead> 
             <tr> 
                 <th>Title</th> 
                 <th>Code</th> 
                 <th>Department</th> 
                 <th>level</th>                      
             </tr> 
         </thead> 
             <tbody> 
                 <tr ng-repeat="course in courses |  filter: adminfilter"> 
                     <td>{{course.name}}</td> 
                     <td>{{course.code}}</td> 
                     <td>{{course.department.name}}</td> 
                     <td>{{course.level}}</td> 
                     <td>
                        <button  ng-click="register({{course._id}})"  class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Register</button>
                     </td>                      
                   </tr> 
             </tbody>
         </table>
      </div
```

and here is the output
[Outout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9OJQ.jpg)

everything works well but when the register button is been click nothing happens. please can anybody help me is they anything i have done wrongly?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz3Ya.jpg)

Comment: Try removing interpolations like `ng-click="register(course._id)" ` and where is your `register()` method in the controller?

Comment: here is the register ' $http.get('/api/student/getcourses/' + $scope.studentid)
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.courses = data ; 
    $scope.register = function(course){
            $http.post('/api/student/courseReg/' + $scope.studentid, course)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
    };
})
.error(function (e) {
    return e;
});     '

Comment: why did you define it inside the $http get call? In this way you are never going to make any call to this `register()` method.

Comment: Please can you show me the correct way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call `register()` method on the $scope, then declaration should be like this.
    **HTML code**

```
       <tbody> 
             <tr ng-repeat="course in courses |  filter: adminfilter"> 
                 <td>{{course.name}}</td> 
                 <td>{{course.code}}</td> 
                 <td>{{course.department.name}}</td> 
                 <td>{{course.level}}</td> 
                 <td>
                    <button  ng-click="register(course._id)"  class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Register</button>
                 </td>                      
               </tr> 
         </tbody>
```

**my.controller.js**

```
  angular.module('myapp').controller('myController', function($scope,$http){

  $scope.studentid = ....

  $http.get('/api/student/getcourses/' + $scope.studentid)
   .success(function(data) {
      $scope.courses = data ; 
   })
  .error(function (e) {
    return e;
  });

  $scope.register = function(course){
        $http.post('/api/student/courseReg/' + $scope.studentid, {course:course}) //watch out *data* field of $http,  it can be either string or an object
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
  });
```

Comment: if i am not using  ng-click="register(course._id)" how else can i  pass the course._id to the register()  function

Comment: what exactly you want to do? Clarify that thing only then I can suggest you other alternatives.

Comment: OK here is it, if you have seen my question, i have two schema studentSchema and courseSchema  i want when the register button is been clicked  the course id from the corresponding course should be push into the array of student.courses field .

Comment: For that, you have to use `ng-click()` directive and pass `course._id` along with as a parameter.Ther is no other possible way to distinguish the course.

Comment: @Emibrown I have updated the HTML part also, it will help you to understand the flow. What exactly happening when you click on register(course._id), it calls register(course) method on the scope, which will make a post request to the `/api/student/courseReg/` with course._id passed along the body params for a particular student.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: i need a way of stopping a student  not to register the same course over and over again